# AngularJS - form inside ng-repeat undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to access form object in my controller. Form lies inside ng-repeat block it has got its dynamic name and I should be able to access it since v1.3.

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.forms = [0];
  $scope.testForm = function() {
    if($scope.form0 == undefined) {
      $scope.test = 'Form is NOT defined';
    } else {
      $scope.test = 'Form is defined';
    }
  }
}])
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="form in forms" ng-init="formName = 'form' + $index">
      form name should be {{formName}}
      <form name="{{formName}}">
        <input type="text" name="field" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <button ng-click="testForm()">Check if form exists</button>
  <p ng-bind="test"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

But in my controller $scope.form0 is undefined - after clicking "Check if form exists" I get "Form is NOT defined" message. Even if I give it a static name (`<form name="form0">`) I still keep getting undefined. When I take form out of the ng-repeat loop, it works fine.

Any idea why it is not set?

The example above:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Fvy5LdIO0H1vCS9wYR0U?p=preview

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `ng-repeat` is creating isolated child scopes, the `form0` is in the child scope and not visible from the parent (the controller's scope).

So the solution is to pass it to the parent. However we cannot do it in ng-init since the form controller is not initialised by that time.

One approach I could think of is having a custom directive to bind the formController to a specified scope.

```
app.directive("form",function($parse){
  return{
    restrict:"E",
    priority:-1,
    link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
      var targetScope = $parse(attrs.bindToScope)(scope);
      if(targetScope){
        targetScope[attrs.name] = scope[attrs.name];
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and with this we can tell the form to bind the controller to the scope we specified.

```
<form name="{{formName}}" bind-to-scope='$parent' >
     <input type="text" name="field" />
</form>
```